# The variance of $X$ is finite if and only if $X$ is square-integrable

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

> > As the title says I want to show for a random variable $X$ on a probability space $(\mathfrak{X},\mathfrak{A},P)$ that
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{V}(X)<\infty\Leftrightarrow X\in\mathcal{L}_{P}^2.
> > $$

"$\Leftarrow$": 
$$
V(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2,
$$
$$
E(X^2)=\int X^2\, dP=\left(\underbrace{\left(\int\lvert X\rvert^2\, dP\right)^{1/2}}_{<\infty}\right)^2<\infty,
$$
$P(X)<\infty\Rightarrow X\in\mathcal{L}_P^1$, i.e.
$$
E(X)=\int\lvert X\rvert\, dP<\infty\Rightarrow (E(X))^2<\infty
$$

So it is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2<\infty$.

"$\Rightarrow$":

$$
E(X^2)-(E(X))^2<\infty\\\Leftrightarrow E(X^2)<\infty\\\Rightarrow (E(X^2))^{1/2}=(\int X^2\, dP)^{1/2}=(\int\lvert X\rvert^2\, dP)^{1/2}<\infty,
$$
i.e. $X\in\mathcal{L}_{P}^2$

Is my proof right?

Answer (score 2):

Both proofs are difficult to read, partly because you do not explain what you are doing. Anyway, it seems that the "$\Leftarrow$" proof (which uses the quite unorthodox "$P(X)<\infty$" notation) is based on the unproven assertion that if $X\in L^2$ then $X\in L^1$. This happens to be true but (1) if indeed this is the crux of the matter, why bother with the squaring-the-square-root-of-the-square steps? and (2) a proof should be given.

Likewise, the "$\Rightarrow$" proof starts by the equivalence
$E(X^2)-(E(X))^2<\infty\Leftrightarrow E(X^2)<\infty$. Well, maybe this holds, maybe this does not (this does), but how do you know?

To sum up, in both directions you introduce casually and with no proof some statements which are in fact equivalent to the ones to be shown.